# How to pass variable from CLI program to Python Views to Update Django UI?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, celery

I have a Django app which calls a CLI app by function call and then CLI app performs action and delivers output. The CLI version has a loading bar which displays the progress of the process, My plan is to integrate it with GUI. The project is huge so I simplied it to a shorter project to make it clear for ya'll to understand. The real app has more nuanced and complex than this demo app

So, I created a tiny demo project to simplify the question for you all.
Project Structure is

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───testapp
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   views.pyc
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   __init__.pyc
│   │
│   ├───cliprog
│   │       cliprogram.py
│   │       cliprogram.pyc
│   │       main.py
│   │
│   └───migrations
│           __init__.py
│
└───testproject
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.py
        wsgi.pyc
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from cliprog.main import view_helper

def index(request):
    view_helper()
    return HttpResponse('It works but CLI')
```

`cliprog/main.py`

```
from cliprogram import nice

def view_helper(): # So, that I can call this function and run my cli code
    # do something
    nice()
    # do something
```

`cliprog/cliprogram.py`

```
# Print iterations progress
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '#'):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print '\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix)
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total:
        print()

#
# Sample Usage
#

from time import sleep
def nice():
# A List of Items
    items = list(range(0, 57))
    l = len(items)

# Initial call to print 0% progress
    printProgressBar(0, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
    # Do stuff...
        sleep(0.1)
    # Update Progress Bar
        printProgressBar(i + 1, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
```

So, when you run `python manage.py runserver` , the idea is that the View runs the CLI program which calculates the percentage ( using total values and current number of samples). But displays it on CLI as that is a CLI program.
Now, what I need is that I want to somehow get `l` and `i` (total and current iteration respectively) from the cli file `cliprogram.py` to views and views will pass it to UI where I will implement GUI version of the loading bar.

Is there a *possibility* that when the function `nice()` is trigerred then it can pass values to `views.py` so I can update a GUI version of Loading Bar?

**Note**:
I already use celery for real app. Just not showing that in the demo app. So, if something is possible using celery to solve it. Answers are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Because `django` is single thread single process in its nature, I think you'll need to use `multiprocessing` or`threading` library to do that. Your idea involves running two pieces of code concurrently. You can open a pipe to pass variables between processes, or read the variable directly if you are using `threading`. Since the example you gave is simplified, I am not trying to modify your code here because it involves major modification of your entire project.

I modified your demo slightly so it can be ran as a standalone script instead of a django project. But the idea remains the same.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


# Print iterations progress
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '#'):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix))
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total:
        print()

#
# Sample Usage
#

from time import sleep
def nice(connection):
# A List of Items
    items = list(range(0, 57))
    l = len(items)

# Initial call to print 0% progress
    printProgressBar(0, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
    # Do stuff...

        sleep(0.1)
    # Update Progress Bar
        connection.send((i,l))
        printProgressBar(i + 1, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
    connection.close()

def view_helper(connection): # So, that I can call this function and run my cli code
    # do something
    nice(connection)
    # do something

def index(): # your django view
    conn1,conn2=mp.Pipe()
    p=mp.Process(target=view_helper,args=(conn2,))
    p.start()
    while True:
        i,l=conn1.recv()
        # do things you want with your i and l
        if i==l-1:
            conn1.close()
            p.terminate()
            break

    #return HttpResponse('It works but CLI')

index()
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You can modify the demo project if you want to, I will try to reproduce it and see if that's possible to integrate with the original project. Because it's a bit tricky.

Comment: I'm already using celery, Is there a better functionality available with celery itself ? @pkqxdd

Comment: I am not very familiar with celery. But I have edited my answer with a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Add a command line flag to your CLI, `--no-bar` or something. When `--no-bar` is enabled, instead of showing the progress bar, just print percentages. Your GUI can read the percentages as a stream and update accordingly.

Note: other print statements in your CLI could mess this up.

**Option 2**

Print your progress bar to `stderr`, but print percentages to `stdout`. Read only `stdout` from your GUI.

Comment: The problem is how would you retrieve those values from `stdout` of CLI by `views.py` . views.py and GUI are linked with each other. So, in order to update anything to GUI. The idea is to first fetch to the `views.py`. But the trickiest part is sending the data to the `views.py`. Do you have any idea for that